# Add Views to LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have an Activity that displays comments. The comments themselves have a layout, so I can't just use a ListView.

I'm adding the comments with a loop, and the program goes through the whole loop (checked via LogCat), but only adds the first View (comment) to the linearlayout.

My code (in reality the fillComments parameter will be something else than String[]):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.comment_layout);
    String[] comments = {"kommentaar 1", "kommentaar 2", "kommentaar 3"};
    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.comments_title);
    mTextArea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment_editor);
    mAddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_comment);
    mCommentArea = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.comments_area);

    mTitle.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));
    fillComments(comments);
}

private void fillComments(String[] comments) {
    View comment;
    TextView commentator;
    TextView commentDate;
    TextView commentText;
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    for (String s : comments) {
        Log.d("Comment adder", "Adding comment " + s);
        comment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_row_layout, null);
        commentator = (TextView) comment.findViewById(R.id.commentator);
        commentDate = (TextView) comment.findViewById(R.id.comment_date);
        commentText = (TextView) comment.findViewById(R.id.comment_text);
        commentator.setText("Test commentator");
        commentDate.setText("12-12-2012");
        commentText.setText(s);
        mCommentArea.addView(comment);
    }
}
```

Comment: It also happens if `R.id.comments_area` has orientation vertical + width fill_parent ? And is the log ("Comment adder") displayed multiple times ?

Comment: can you please show us layout: comment_row_layout.xml.. I can guess you have horizontal orientation...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think 
`mCommentArea = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.comments_area);` 
this layout orientation is Horizontal so this problems occurs. please if horizontal orientations then please change it to vertical and enjoy

Answer (score 2):

How have you defined the LinearLayout? It could be just a display issue.
Check the size and orientation of LinearLayout.

Comment: You're right, I'd forgot to add the `android:orientation="vertical"` line to my LinearLayout.